# How to get ApplicationBarMenuItem Name in ApplicationBarMenuItemClick Event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working in Windows Phone 7.5 application. I am unable to find `ApplicationBarMenuItem` name from Single Click Events.

Comment: The name is not accessible. Why do you need to get at the name?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation it doesn't look like Name is a supported Property of that class. So you will have to use the Text property or something like that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbarmenuitem(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I have a snippet for `switch((sender as ApplicationBarMenuItem).Text){}` that I use in every click event.

Comment: using `Text` is what's done in the `Silverlight Toolkit` source - which makes seem like a pretty decent approach.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to identify the Menu Item you have clicked on is to iterate through the menu items collection and attempting to match the (Sender as ApplicationBarMenuItem).Text to each one. The matching ones index can then be used to determine which item you have tapped.